# 2 devices with different CAN baud

Tags: can, baudrate, st, bom

I have a project where I need to talk with 2 devices x & y with 125kbps and 500kbps CAN speeds respectively.
So I selected an MCU (F446RC) with 2 CAN controllers from ST. The BOM cost went up and I'm not able to meet the target cost.

Is there a way to handle 2 speeds on same bus? or please suggest any cost-effective method.

Comment: Even if your device was the master, CAN does not have a clock in data, so you cannot have two different speeds on the same bus.  Both devices would be confused.   Controller has two CANs so all we are talking about here is tranceiver, some discretes and a connector.  Any solution (CAN complient bus switch - if they exist) would have more cost than this.

Comment: @stainlessSteelRat - okay. Can you suggest some alternative ways to optimize bom cost?

Comment: Do you need that much firepower for the MCU itself? DSP, FPU and so on? I'm certain there's smaller Cortex M with 2 or more CAN. Though list price is just $3.3/10k I guess.

Comment: Also, how much protection did you add to the CAN lines? TVS, chokes, terminators etc?

Comment: @Lundin - I have added ESDCAN02 to CAN lines.

Comment: @Lundin - volumes are not high in my case. It might be 300-500 per/annum. I did check out some other MCUs but people from ST recommended this as the best moving part right now and have huge discounts in bulk. Can you suggest any?

Comment: Depending on your application, you might not need those diodes. The transceiver itself is very rugged and protected from ESD. You'd only add TVS if you have specific automotive requirements or such. An EMI choke might be useful though, but I guess adding one won't help your BOM cost :)

Comment: @MANI As for the MCU, they are really super cheap nowadays. Only a decade back you'd have to pay five times the price or so. It's generally the last component I'd be cheap about, but then picking a high-end MCU might be expensive in other ways, since they are usually more intricate to configure and add lots of complexity that you might not benefit from.

Comment: @lundin BTW I am using SN65HVD232. So you suggest removing ESDs. Okay. Thanks. I'll read datasheet again though before removing.

Comment: Those are fairly rugged, I've been using that exact part in industrial applications without TVS protection. I'd probably recommend something like MPC2562 for new designs though. You can configure it to work with 3V3 as well as 5V.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs :). Maybe I should use 2 low cost MCUs to reduce the bom cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two speeds on one bus. So I have no idea but using 2 busses. Maybe you can set one device to busoff, then talk to the other and then do the same but with switched devices... but it will not work if the devices expect cyclic communication with the master. CAN is designed for all devices with one speed, as the devices need to know the bit-timing.

Comment: Can you suggest some alternative ways to optimize bom cost?

Comment: We are more or less talking about an additional 1,17€ CAN transeiver (from the most expensive dealer I know here) plus a connector plus some board space... lets say 3€ at all. any tricks with some transistors (and resistors) won't be any better or much cheeper. Guess a coffee at starbucks is more expensive. StainlessSteelRat's Comment under your question is absolute right. You have a µC with double CAN already, so just do 2 CAN's. Thats the most easy and least error prone way. And a normal CAN is quite robust, so you normally just need transeiver, termination and connector

Comment: https://www.conrad.de/de/p/microchip-technology-mcp2551-i-p-schnittstellen-ic-transceiver-can-1-1-pdip-8-651451.html ...my company uses Microchips 2551 in industrial products. just to mention that. so that device has a good quality

Comment: 2551 works on 3.3V logic?

Comment: the datasheet states "Device drivers will function, although outputs are not ensured to meet the ISO-11898 specification". So if the device can not generate standard levels, which are ~5V, you can assume all devices suffer the same problem. What will happen? you will loose cable length and EMI robustness to a certain degree.

Comment: I'm going to use MPC2562FD. Thanks for the inputs. But my question is fully not answered. Maybe I should use 2 low cost MCUs to reduce bom costs?

Comment: you will need more pcb area, 2 times programming time,... 2 µC cant be cheeper in most cases

Comment: What if I use 2 STM32F042F6P6 instead of 1 STM32F446RCT6?

Comment: the smaller is about 40% of the price, only has less than a 3rd of the pins and the M0 instruction set is much more limited than the M0 - so some code will need more clock cycles to do the same... Are you really bothering about a single €/$? in quantities the difference will be even less. And you need min. 1cm² more PCB if not more, 2 programming interfaces, guess you need communication between the µC, so its more complex, worse timing and you waste pins, I do not see any advantage to it. in the end you will not save a penny.BOM cost is not everything. Dual CAN is normally a high cost feature.

Comment: Your problem is the 2 devices with different CAN speeds. If you want to have a sane system architecture with cheep µC, you need other devices with same speed or a complete other bus.